# Laravel sanctum csrf cookie set issue "attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie header was blocked because its Domain attribute..."

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I have an issue with the Laravel Sanctum CSRF Cookie's.
I run an API with Laravel 8 on a subdomain: api.domain.nl
And a front end with NuxtJS on domain.nl
Now I want to protect my POST requests that are going to the api.domain.nl with a CSRF cookie that's set on the front end.
To achieve this I read about Laravel Sanctum. Now I am sending a POST request to api.domain.nl/api/sanctum/csrf-cookie, this returns a 204 status and tries to do a SET-COOKIE header.
On localhost, this works fine. But whenever I try to do it on my server I get this error:

```
This attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie header was blocked because its Domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host URL
```

[image: This attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie header was blocked because its Domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host URL]

Now I did read about some other people that ran into this issue.
And it has something to do with your Laravel .env
I tried everything with the **SESSION_DOMAIN** and **SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS** but honestly, I'm clueless cause it kept giving me the same error.
For now, I have this:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.domain.nl
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN=api.domain.nl
```

*(Of course domain replaced with the domain I use)*

Hope someone has the solution to this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Is it really working on the local environment with the following .env setup?

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN=api.domain.nl
```

I guess this SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN should be your front-end URL.

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN=http://domain.nl
```

I hope this will work.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried running `php artisan optimize:clear` just make sure Laravel is not referencing the an old configuration?

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."